# Appcelerator Studio Editor crash

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-studio

I work with Titanium platform since 2012 and I have a "very long" solution composed of almost 100 js files and someone with 2000 rows.

After a few months of stop I decided to refresh all the binaries with the last version and with the last edition of AppceleratorStudio I have a very strange error.

Appcelerator Studio immediatly crash when I try to collapse the first function on certain JS files.

Then the Mac debug screen show me the following

---

```
Process:               AppceleratorStudio [10503]
Path:                  /Applications/Appcelerator Studio/AppceleratorStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/AppceleratorStudio
Identifier:            com.appcelerator.appcelerator-studio
Version:               5.0.0 (5.0.0.201712081732)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           AppceleratorStudio [10503]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-06-03 09:25:07.416 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E202)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        2D63CD60-ABAD-C176-FE94-7AC468ABA6B4

Sleep/Wake UUID:       2CBEAF96-502D-43B5-8594-450FA90406B0

Time Awake Since Boot: 100000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       88000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000012ab00000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

---

I didn't find a logic so far so any help is very appreciated because I need to continue to develop the App.

By the way everthing else is working and I can succesfully compile and launch a simulation of the App.

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

Issue is similar to this https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-8916 where editor is getting crashed randomly when they are working on the JS code.

Fix will be part of the Studio 5.1.0 release.

If you're blocked please try the 5.1.0 preview build from here http://preview.appcelerator.com/appc-studio/ and and this should work for you.

And, make sure you get the 5.1.0 GA when it's available!